# Why that Java program isn't painting?

Tags: java

I have problem, my program isn't compiling. I'm trying to paint dots from my file where I have records to calculate. I don't know where is the problem. When I'm trying to run that, console is showing errors but JFrame is opening. There are black layout with two recentagles. **It should head conture!**  Errors:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 504542, Size: 504540
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at rysuje.Rysowanie.wezLiczbe(Rysowanie.java:40)
    at rysuje.Rysowanie.paintComponent(Rysowanie.java:57)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 504542, Size: 504540
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at rysuje.Rysowanie.wezLiczbe(Rysowanie.java:40)
    at rysuje.Rysowanie.paintComponent(Rysowanie.java:57)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Program:

```
      package rysuje;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Rysowanie extends JPanel {

    ArrayList<Double> liczby = new ArrayList<Double>();

    public Rysowanie () {
        try {
            File file = new File("pliki/wynik5.xyz");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            input.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

            while (input.hasNextDouble()) {
                dodajLiczbe(input.nextDouble());
            }
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Załadowalem tyle plikow: "+ileLiczb());
    }

    public void dodajLiczbe(double liczba) {
        liczby.add(liczba);
    }

    public Double wezLiczbe(int indeks) {
        return liczby.get(indeks);
    }

    public int ileLiczb() {
        return liczby.size();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        int x;
        int z;
        int c = 0;
        int d = (int) 0.1;
        int e = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < liczby.size(); i++) {
            x = (int) (wezLiczbe(e) * Math.sin(wezLiczbe(c) * Math.pow(10, -6)));
            z = (int) (wezLiczbe(e) * Math.cos(wezLiczbe(c) * Math.pow(10, -6)));

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawOval(x, z, d, d);
            if (c < liczby.size()-3 ) {
            c = c + 3;
            }
            else if (e < liczby.size()-3) {
            e = e + 3;
            }
        }
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("NIE WIEM");
        JPanel world = new Rysowanie();
        frame.getContentPane().add(world);
        frame.setLocation(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not painting because you need to fix your `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception on this line: `Rysowanie.java:40`. So which line is that?

Comment: See [IOOBE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

Comment: Okay, sorry for that sentence. @HovercraftFullOfEels
In 40 line is:  ` return liczby.get(indeks); `. Can you tell me what is the problem with that line?

Comment: your `indeks` is greater than the size of `ArrayList` `liczby`

Comment: A quick turn in an IDE with a debugger will show you in five minutes where your assumptions fail to match reality.

Comment: Now is better, guys?

Answer (score 2):

when you call

```
 e = e + 3;
```

in your for loop you are getting IndexOutOfBounds when calling

```
wezLiczbe(e)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    int e = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < liczby.size(); i++) {
        x = (int) (wezLiczbe(e) * Math.sin(wezLiczbe(c) * Math.pow(10, -6)));
        z = (int) (wezLiczbe(e) * Math.cos(wezLiczbe(c) * Math.pow(10, -6)));

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawOval(x, z, d, d);
        c = c + 3;
        e = e + 3;
    }
```

You're over-running the `liczby` array.

You're iterating `i` from `0` to `liczby.size()`, which is valid.  But, you're accessing that same array (via the `wezLiczbe()` method) with `e` from `2` to `(2 + 3*liczby.size())` which is way too big. I don't know what you're trying to do (b/c I don't speak Polish?) but your logic is very wrong.

Comment: @JoeMichu: why ask if it's OK now -- what happens when you run your program now?

Comment: When you edit the code, you make all the answers invalid.

Comment: Program is to slow, compiling is to slow.. should I wait ~1 hour to see first results? I don't know is that program working well.